# How to make scores with different baselines comparable---compare the quality of edible vegetation for several bird species in the same area?

Tags: normalization, biostatistics, standardization

To give some background to my problem, I want to compare the quality of edible vegetation for several bird species in the same area. The birds eat some of the same food resources, but there are also plants that are only consumed by one species. This results in different sizes (area in ha) of edible vegetation for the different species. To add to this, the quality of the edible vegetation varies for each species. I would like to compare the proportions of high-quality edible vegetation for each species in a way that also accounts for the differing sizes (areas in ha) of edible vegetation.

For example, there is 1 ha of high-quality edible vegetation and 3 ha of low-quality edible vegetation for 'species 1'. For 'species 2', there is also 1 ha of high-quality edible vegetation, but only 0.5 ha of low-quality edible vegetation. Thus, there is a total of 4 ha edible vegetation for species 1 and 1.5 ha for species 2 of total edible vegetation.
The proportions of edible vegetation quality are 25% high-quality and 75% low-quality for species 1. For species 2, it is 67% high quality and 33% low quality. This makes it look like the edible vegetation is better for species 1.

However, the area of high-quality edible vegetation is actually the same for both species (1 ha) and there is a larger total area of edible vegetation for species 1. So the result should be that the vegetation is better quality for species 1 overall. Is there a way to account for or normalize the differing total areas of edible vegetation to make the proportion measures comparable?

Comment: Welcome to CrossValidated! Could you double-check your statement "This makes it look like the edible vegetation is better for species 1."? Isn't species 2? 67% > 25%.

Comment: A good title helps to attract attention to your question. I tried to improve, please consider and maybe your own edits!